# get key list in descending order in lua scipt

Tags: lua, redis, lua-table

I have one list in redis key store. it's containing date as keyname like this.

```
key  
===  
20160429 
20160430 
20160501
20160502
```

Now I want to key last 2 keys, for this I am doing following in my lua script.

```
local data = {};
local keyslist = redis.call('keys', 'stats:day:*');
local key, users, redisData;
-- keyslist = #keyslist.sort(#keyslist, function(a, b) return a[2] > b[2] end);
-- keyslist = #keyslist.sort(#keyslist, function(a,b) if a>b then return true; else return false; end end); 
for iCtr = 1, #keyslist do

    key = string.gsub(keyslist[iCtr], 'stats:day:','');
    redisData = redis.call('hmget', keyslist[iCtr], 'image','video');
    table.insert(data, {date=key, imgctr=redisData[1], vidctr=redisData[2]});
    if iCtr == 2 then break end
end
```

but this is returning first 2 records, I need last 2 records (e.g. following keys)

```
20160501
20160502
```

How Do I get descending key list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you might want to do the following:

```
local count = 0
for iCtr = #keyslist-1,#keyslist do
  count=count+1
  --do your stuff
  if count == 2 then break end
  --or
  if iCtr == #keyslist then break end
end
```

This will start at the penultimate item in the keyslist and then count upwards.
Note, I did not test the code, but it should work..

Comment: thanks @felixb, It's is very close to my expected result. I need final result in ASC order, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I updated the code, now it takes always the last two elements and gives them in their corresponding order. Hope that helps (still untested)

Comment: thanks, its works with little change : for iCtr = #keyslist-1,#keyslist do

Comment: ah, yeah, right. This always happens to me. I ll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for sorting a Lua table:

```
keylist = {1,2,5,8,3, 5}

-- after the following line keylist will be sorted ascending (default)

table.sort(keylist)

-- this line is equivalent:

table.sort(keylist, function (a,b) return a < b end)
```

the second parameter is to table.sort is a function that takes two table values and returns true if the first one is smaller than the second one.

To sort a table decending you simply call

```
table.sort(keylist, function(a,b)return a > b end)
```

Please keep in mind that you can only use this to sort the table values, not their keys. But as you are using keys in a different context this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @piglet for replying me. I have tried my level best to explain my problem, but due to my poor English, may be I am not explain it properly, really very sorry for that.

Comment: @ManishSapkal I changed my answer a bit, I was confused by your use of "key". Hope this is better help now?